# Как сохранить файл (.xls, .xlsx) с помощью new Blob() в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, download, extjs

С бэка аяксом беру (xlsx) файл, приходит в виде: [image: responseText]

Мне необходимо сохранить его на клиенте.
Если сделать без аякса `window.open('/api/getbyuuid/0e0ca8e1-176 ...', '_blank')`, то файл автоматически скачивается и открывается без проблем.
Я же пытаюсь сделать через `new Blob()`:

```js
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: '/api/ks/share/' + record.id,
  method: 'GET',
  success: function (response, opts) {
    // console.log(response.responseText)
    let type = response.getResponseHeader('Content-Type'),
      blob = new Blob([response.responseText], { type: type }),
      disposition = response.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition'),
      filename = disposition
        .slice(disposition.indexOf('=') + 1, disposition.length)
        .replace(/['"]/g, '')

    if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    } else if (filename) {
      let URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
        downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob),
        a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = downloadUrl;
      a.target = '_blank';
      a.download = filename;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      a.parentNode.removeChild(a);

      setTimeout(() => { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl) }, 100);
    }
  },
  failure: function (response, opts) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Файл сохраняет, но при попытке открыть выдает ошибку:

[image: Ошибка 1]

При нажатии на "Да":

[image: Ошибка 2]

Comment: Сравните побайтово файлы: оригинал и битый. Для начала можете просто размеры сравнить.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Поизучал еще данный вопрос, файл приходит в два раза больше оригинала, но это не проблема, тут дело в кодировании символов при передаче. Дело в том что через обычный ajax запрос это не всегда получается, поигрался с параметрами запроса ```responseType: 'blob'```, но и это не помогло.

Comment: Есть решение этого вопроса через fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это работает для меня

```
fetch('/api/ks/share/' + record.id,)
      .then(resp => resp.blob())
      .then(blob => {
        let URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
            downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob),
            a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = downloadUrl;
        a.target = '_blank';
        a.download = record.id;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
        setTimeout(() => { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl) }, 100);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```